What is the best way to upload a serialized IAsyncEnumerable to Azure Blob Storage
We receive a lot of records from a remote server in the form of IAsyncEnumerable and after a simple convert and JSON serialization we are trying to upload the result (a JSON file) to Azure Blob Storage.
Is there any way I can improve this code to reduce the maximum memory usage. The number of records we receive from the remote server is high.
public async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    var items = GetItems();

    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(memoryStream, items);

    var blobContainerClient = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient("connectionString", "container");
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("blobName");

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, overwrite: true);
}

private static async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
    // This is calling a remote server that returns IAsyncEnumerable<Row>
    await foreach (var row in GetIAsyncEnumerable())
    {
        yield return new Item(row);
    }
}

Up until the JSON Serilization everything seems fine, we recive the records one-by-one and converting the object type and serilization happens one-by-one too.
But after await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(memoryStream, items) we wait for all the items to finish and materialize in the memory and then we start the upload.
Is there any way we can continue this chain of IAsyncEnumerables and start the upload as soon as first item is received and continue uploading for each new object?

You can open a stream to the blob directly and serialize the items to it.
public async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient("connectionString", "container");
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("blobName");

    var items = GetItems();
    await using var blobStream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true);
    await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(blobStream, items);
}

To be able to write the items as they become available you would need something like this:
public async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient("connectionString", "container");
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("blobName");

    var items = GetItems();
    await using var blobStream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true);
    await using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(blobStream, new JsonWriterOptions { Indented = true });

    writer.WriteStartArray();
    await foreach (var item in items)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item);
        await writer.FlushAsync(); // If you want the item immediately to be available in the blob. For better performance remove.
    }
    writer.WriteEndArray();

    await writer.FlushAsync();
}


Do you really have to FlushAsync() after each item?

@Magnus thank you for you answer. I've changed the SerializeAsync to Serialize in your second sample to make it work. It seems like a very good approach but the result is very slow, like two three orders of magnitude slower than the original and I'm not sure why.

Try removing the flush in the loop. It will then flush when the buffer is full.
